# Webpack error after fixing vulnerabilities

Tags: laravel, webpack, vuejs2

I'm getting a webpack error after npm audit fix for a Laravel/Vue2 project.

I'd really appreciate any help. I'm a beginner, so please bear with me.
Thank you so much!

This is the full error message:

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'svg-files-path')
    at SvgVue.webpackConfig (/Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/laravel-mix-svg-vue/index.js:67:55)
    at /Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js:124:54
    at /Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:39:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Dispatcher.fire (/Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:39:47)
    at Mix.dispatch (/Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:248:32)
    at WebpackConfig.build (/Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:37:24)
    at async loadConfigByPath (/Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1439:31)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async WebpackCLI.loadConfig (/Users/[username]/Coding/GitHub/onlinebooking/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1454:35)
```

And this the code that causes the error:

```
    webpackConfig(webpackConfig) {
        let fs = require('fs');

        fs.mkdir(this.includePath, error => {
            if (error && error.code === 'EEXIST') return null;
        });

        webpackConfig.resolve.alias['svg-files-path'] = this.includePath;

        if (this.options.extract) {
            let svgAssetsObj = {
                test: this.includePath,
                name: '/js/svg',
                chunks: 'all',
                enforce: true
            }

            if (webpackConfig.optimization.hasOwnProperty('splitChunks')) {
                webpackConfig.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups['svgAssets'] = svgAssetsObj;
            } else {
                webpackConfig.optimization = {
                    splitChunks: {
                        cacheGroups: {
                            svgAssets: svgAssetsObj
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```